# --explicitly-allowed-ports equivalent chromium on linux

Tags: linux, chromium, raspberry-pi

I need chromium on a raspberry pi to be able to browse to a website residing on a arbitary port "111" in this case. However chromium complains (I understand for good reason). However I need to get chromium to allow this for a company test app. I found that on Chrome for Windows you can set --explicitly-allowed-ports but how do I do it on the Pi and for chromium?

Comment: What happens if you open `http://some.url.com:111`?

Comment: I get a page not found error. If I browse to it in IE it works fine... If I use opera I get a port not allowed error.

Comment: Hang on, does it work with another browser on the Pi? I assume IE is on windows.

Comment: I am not sure as the pi boots straight in to chromium. Other websites work fine (although I have to hit refresh after initial boot due to some proxy issue which no one on this earth seems to be able to answer). I will change the config and see if midori accepts port 111

Comment: Also just to fill in the gap. Chrome on Windows complains as does Opera for windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit `/etc/chromium-browser/default` and add the flag to CHROMIUM_FLAGS

`CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--disable-new-tab-first-run --enable-user-scripts --explicitly-allowed-ports=XXXX"`